# How do I export Stata dataset to multiple csv files by range of observations?

Tags: stata

I have a Stata dataset with about 50,000 observations. How do I export it into multiple csv files in batches of 1000 observations per csv?

I am not sure how to run a loop. I have only been doing it manually such as

```
export delimited using file_1 in 1/1000, replace
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach where I suggest some best practices that I would use when doing this.

```
* Sort file to make this reproducible as row order is used when expertiong the file
isid <IDVARIABLE>, sort  // Sorting like this guarantees a unique sort order

* Loop over lower bounds
forvalues lower = 1(1000)50000 {
    
    * Calulate upper bounds
    local upper = `lower' + 999

    * Export csv file 
    export delimited using file_l`lower'_u`upper' in `lower'/`upper', replace
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This did the trick!